# How to filter an array for a complete match?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays. First, the original array of objects. And the second is an array to search through the original array

```
  const originalArray = [
    {
      name: "1",
      arrayStrings: ["Text1", "Text2"],
    },
    {
      name: "2",
      arrayStrings: ["Text1", "Text2", "Text3"],
    },
  ];

  const arrayForSearch = ["Text1", "Text2", "Text3"];
```

I need to write a function that would check the arrayStrings of each object in the original array against the arrayForSearch array and return that object to a new array only if all elements from arrayForSearch are present in its arrayStrings array. I tried different approaches, but every time the function does not work for me as I want it to. I can not understand to use a cycle or it is possible through the methods of working with arrays.

Comment: Checkout jsondiff.js https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-diff

Comment: i need native solution

Comment: so arrayStrings can have more elements than arrayForSearc?

Comment: `originalArray.filter(({arrayStrings})=>arrayForSearch.every(e => arrayStrings.includes(e)))` but this will only check if every el in arrayForSearch is in arrayStrings. not opposite

Comment: @pilchard not really . I did this through every , but I need not just true -false , but return a full-fledged object if it matches

Comment: That's the role of [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter). Simply use the duplicate within a `filter()` call – `true` includes the object in the result array, `false` excludes it.

Comment: I got the answer in the comments above from users plichard and cmgchess . Thank them very much!